# Number() vs new Number()?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I'm trying to understand the difference between writing `m =  Number()` (which causes `typeof m` to evaluate as `"number"`) vs `m = new Number()` (which causes `typeof m` to evaluate as `"object"`).

I would have expected it to be an `object` either way. I was just messing around, and I added a `.helloWorld()` method to the `Number` prototype, and I was able to access it on `m` regardless of which method I used to instantiate it.

What's the difference here? What am I doing differently between writing `Number()` and `new Number()`? Why is one an `object` while the other is a `number`?

Comment: executing a constructor without `new` can clobber the `window` object.

Comment: The graphs in this series of articles clarified the JS object model for me: http://howtonode.org/object-graphs-2.

Comment: "[*When **Number** is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type conversion.*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.1)" vs. "[*When **Number** is called as part of a **new** expression it is a constructor: it initialises the newly created object.*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.2)"

Comment: Ahhhhhh....javascript doesn't take the "everything is an object" approach. GOTCHA.

Comment: @Aerovistae—quite the opposite—everything is an object, but primitives are provided for convenience. Primitives are coerced to object where helpful: `var x = 10; x.toString(16); /* A */`.

Comment: Why the upvotes?  It's a duplicate!

Comment: Because a lot of people never saw the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Number()` by itself returns a number primitive. When you call `new Number()` you receive a new instance of an Object which represents `Number`'s ([relevant ES5 spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.1)).

When you call a property on a primitive, the primitive is auto-boxed (like in Java) to an instance of that object, which is what lets you call `helloWorld()` on either the `object` or `number`.

However, try this;

```
var x = Number(5);
x.bar = function (x) { alert(x); };
x.bar("hello");

var y = new Number(5);
y.bar = function (x) { alert(x); };
y.bar("hello");
```

You'll see the latter works whilst the former does not; in the first, the `number` is autoboxed to a number, and the `bar` method is added to it (the object). When you call `x.bar()` you're creating a *new* auto-boxed Number, which `bar` doesn't exist on.

In the latter, you're adding a `bar` method to that Number instance, which behaves like any other Object instance, and therefore it persists throughout the lifetime of the object.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use the same name for global/local/parameter name; it heightens the confusion when doing so in an example.  I suggest using a different parameter name other than `x` for your anonymous functions.

Answer (score 3):

This is just how it is implemented. This particular constructor function, when called without `new`, returns a primitive number. When called with `new`, it returns the object-wrapped number.

You can access prototype methods/properties on primitives because behind the scenes, JavaScript converts them to objects, calls the prototype method, and then throws away the object copy. This allows you to do things like:

```
var myString = "foo";
console.log( myString.length ); //=> 3
console.log( typeof myString ); //=> "string"
```

An object copy of the primitive gets made on line two, the length property of the object is checked, and then the object copy is thrown away. `myString` stays as a string primitive.